# Standard bootstrap main menu with dropdown?

Tags: routes, navigation

When using bootstrap with drupal what is the standard way to create a main menu?

When I add the main menu block to a region it does not display as a bootstrap navbar.

When I try with superfish I can add some classes but for example the active-trail cant be changed on li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "standard" Bootstrap subtheme launches with your "standard" Bootstrap Nav Bar. For most intents and purposes this is the main-menu... links added to the main menu at admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu appear there ...

Oddly the navbar isn't available to configure from the blocks page as you might expect nevertheless ... there are some navbar options available under admin/appearance/your-bootstrap-subtheme/settings.

Comment: Jeez, searched for a while. Enabling the main menu on the theme settings page added all of the default classes. Showing the main menu in blocks is what caused the problem